# Is it possible to exclude one specific stopword from a text search dictionary in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search, tsvector

I created this custom dictionary

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.simple_dict (
TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
STOPWORDS = dutch);
```

However, the following stopword is removed:

```
SELECT ts_lexize('public.simple_dict','geen');
```

This word negates the next word and is crucial in terms of meaning. How could we remove this word from the stopwords list?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new stop word file in the `tsearch_data` subdirectory of your PostgreSQL installation's "share" directory by copying `dutch.stop` and removing the offending word.

If the new stop word file is called `dutch_new.stop`, create a new dictionary with

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY dutch_new (
   TEMPLATE = snowball,
   LANGUAGE = 'dutch',
   STOPWORDS = 'dutch_new'
);
```

Then create a new text search configuration using the dictionary:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION dutch_new (COPY = dutch);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION dutch_new
   ALTER MAPPING FOR
      asciihword, asciiword, hword, hword_asciipart, hword_part, word
      WITH dutch_new;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to hardcode the list in some kind of an extension?

Comment: You can certainly use [PGXS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html) to install software that does that.